# Shell Script - Getting a specified value from returned block

Tags: shell, sh

I wish to get the returned value of `status` with shell then I can process to next command

```
# glance image-show 0227a985-cb1e-4f0c-81cb-003411988ea5
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Property            | Value                                |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| checksum            | None                                 |
| container_format    | bare                                 |
| created_at          | 2021-03-15T02:54:15Z                 |
| disk_format         | raw                                  |
| hw_disk_bus         | scsi                                 |
| hw_qemu_guest_agent | yes                                  |
| hw_scsi_model       | virtio-scsi                          |
| id                  | 0227a985-cb1e-4f0c-81cb-003411988ea5 |
| locations           | []                                   |
| min_disk            | 0                                    |
| min_ram             | 0                                    |
| name                | not_inuse                            |
| os_hash_algo        | None                                 |
| os_hash_value       | None                                 |
| os_hidden           | False                                |
| os_require_quiesce  | yes                                  |
| owner               | 4d97a99e53bd4b51aa58601985776d5c     |
| protected           | False                                |
| size                | None                                 |
| status              | active                               |
| tags                | []                                   |
| updated_at          | 2021-03-15T02:54:30Z                 |
| virtual_size        | Not available                        |
| visibility          | private                              |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

How do I get the printed value = `active` ??

```
# glance image-show 0227a985-cb1e-4f0c-81cb-003411988ea5 | grep status
| status              | active                                                                           |
```

Please help, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
# glance image-show 0227a985-cb1e-4f0c-81cb-003411988ea5 | grep status | awk '{print $4}'
active
```

Comment: `awk '/status/ {print $4}'` and you don't need `grep`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Maybe better `awk '$2=="status" {print $4}'`, to cath the case that the _name_ line would also contain the word _status_ as value.

Comment: @user1934428, ... Shouldn't be a risk for names whose values are guaranteed to be hex-formatted uuids, but certainly the better practice in general.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Correct, but the current value of `name` is, for instance, not a uuid, but has the value `in_use`, and the value of `hw_scsi_model` also is not a uuid. Actually, I have no idea where this table came from, so I thought it's better to be on the safe side.